# How do I wire a 4 terminal light fixture

Tags: electrical

How do I wire a porcelain ceiling light fixture with two sets of terminals (two hot/two neutral) instead of the usual two terminal fixture?

Comment: Is it a multiple light fixture?  Are there two different sets of lights that turn on with different switches?

Comment: A picture might be helpful.  Since you don't have enough rep to post one yourself, you can upload it to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and share a link to it in a comment here.  A higher reputation user will be able to edit the image into your question. Images often help members of the community give more specific, more useful answers.

Comment: Look up the model number, look up the original information sheet, do what it says.

Answer (score 3):

Black to black to black.
White to white to white.

All they've done in your light fixture's case is not bother to connect the wires for you ahead of time.  You'll just be wiring the lights up in parallel yourself.  It's always hot to hot and neutral to neutral.

Comment: I think we need more info per Chris Cudmore's and Tester101's comments.

Comment: Perhaps - but on cheaper fixtures (the kinds of fixtures I use in my rentals) they don't bother to join them all for you, so I just assumed this was one of those style.

Comment: I think @TheEvilGreebo is correct.  It's probably a two light fixture, and you just chain the wires.

Comment: He may be right, but we don't even know if there are two lamps. There may be, and perhaps it is a very basic high/low setup (one lamp is low, two lamps are high), etc. Or maybe it is just a daisy chain device to allow easy wiring for downstream lamps without pigtailing. More info would make for a better answer.

Comment: Either way, if there are no downstream devices, its still black to black, white to white.